# Not able to stop dbms_scheduler job

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler

```
SQL> Exec  Dbms_Scheduler.stop_job('US_ALERT',true);
begin Dbms_Scheduler.stop_job('US_ALERT',true); end;
ORA-27466: internal scheduler error: 1870
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 227
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 674
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Does anyone has any idea of what's going wrong here ?
Database : Oracle
Version : 12c

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by the stack being unwound by unhandled exceptions in pl/SQL code.  Most likely the scheduler is executing a procedure with some bad code in it.  (See http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06512.php)

The first thing to do is drop the job

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB('myjob1');
END;
/
```

Then start investigating your stored procedure(s) and add in some exception handling.

For example you might have some pl/sql code as follows

```
DECLARE pe_ratio NUMBER(3,1); 
BEGIN 
SELECT price / earnings INTO pe_ratio FROM stocks WHERE symbol = 'XYZ'; -- might cause division-by-zero error 
INSERT INTO stats (symbol, ratio) VALUES ('XYZ', pe_ratio); COMMIT;
End;
```

If this was called by your job it could result in a ora 06512. (You probably will need to add in some logging/traces into to your pl/SQL to narrow this down, the line numbers in the error messages you reported may also help)

Replace it with

```
DECLARE pe_ratio NUMBER(3,1);   
BEGIN 
SELECT price / earnings INTO pe_ratio FROM stocks WHERE symbol = 'XYZ'; -- might cause division-by-zero error
INSERT INTO stats (symbol, ratio) VALUES ('XYZ', pe_ratio);
 COMMIT; 
EXCEPTION -- exception handlers  begin 
WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN -- handles 'division by zero' error 
INSERT INTO stats (symbol, ratio) VALUES ('XYZ', NULL); 
COMMIT; ... 
WHEN OTHERS THEN -- handles all other errors 
ROLLBACK; 
END; -- exception handlers and block end here
```

No more unhandled exceptions should result in no more ora 06512 errors and therefore your job will stop when when requested.

Here's some good info on exception handling in oracle
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you share some proof of concept ?

Comment: I've updated the answer above with some links and an example.

Comment: Here's an example of someone with a similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20178030/dbms-scheduler-drop-job-only-if-exists